# Closing += (s, e) =>

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

How to handle closing event with windows X(close) button? (a message box with "yes/no-question")

```
public MainWindow()
{
    // some other code
    Closing += (s, e) => ViewModelLocator.Cleanup();
}
```

Actually I understood that the `Closing += (s,e)` calls `ViewModelLocator.Cleanup()` which handles the unregistering of instances but what I wanted to do is to cancel the closing event when clicking on `"No"` button of the message box that appears.

Comment: Read this documentation, reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/application-management-overview#Application_Shutdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Closing` is an event, which can be subscribed to. Subscribing to an event is specifying what actions should be taken when an event occurs.

`Closing` event is self-explanatory and it is risen when window is closed.

Subscribing to an event, in other words, means that you just "tell" what method should be executed. Said method should match delegate, which is

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
   ...
}
```

where `Window_Closing` is just name of a method accrodingly to convention `{object name}_{event name}`.

Instead you can pass lambda expression, as you posted, which matches said delegate.

So code you presented:

```
Closing += (s, e) => ViewModelLocator.Cleanup();
```

is just subscribing to an event. Method is just one method invocation `ViewModelLocator.Cleanup();`.

If you need to show messagebox on that event you could simply write your method (I will continue with example of lambda expression):

```
Closing += (s, e) => 
{
  var result = MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to close?", MessageBoxButton.YesNo);
  e.Cancel = result != MessageBoxresult.Yes;

  if(!e.Cancel)
    ViewModelLocator.Cleanup();
};
```

Comment: it actually works, thanks for informations!

Comment: If the user selects "No" you still want to  "cleanup" the viewmodel?  That seems unlikely.

Comment: @Andy You're right, thanks.

Comment: @BillalOuali Then you should accept the answer (green check mark on the left) and optionally upvote.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn I actually adapted the code with what I needed. I made a condition and an if to call the cleanUp function. thanks

Answer (score 0):

From a technical perspective, this is a [lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions) with s and e as parameters. Since e is the FormClosingEventArgs, you can decide if the the form is closed with

```
e.Cancel = false;
```

or

```
e.Cancel = true;
```

Comment: Does this answer the question "Can any one tell me what this does really mean and how to use it to handle closing event with windows X button?"?

Comment: If i didnt missunderstood his question, i think it does.